# How to set view attribute from custom attr on a custom Preference class?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have created a class `CustomPreference`, which inherits from the androidx Preference class, for the purpose of setting a custom layout made of my own components. And I defined a styleable attr on that custom Preference class. But now I'm trying to understand how to pass along the value from that custom styleable attr on to the attribute on my underlying `SpecialCustomComponent`.

**CustomPreference.java**

```js
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

  private Context context;
  private AttributeSet attrs;

  public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
      int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_widget_custom);
  }

  // other required constructor overloads omitted

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    
    // calling this method here results in an error because
    // a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PreferenceWidgetCustom_preferenceTitle, 0) 
    // returns no resource Id at this point
    setPreferenceTitle(holder);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAttachedToHierarchy(PreferenceManager preferenceManager) {
    super.onAttachedToHierarchy(preferenceManager);
    this.preferenceManager = preferenceManager;

    // alternatively, calling this method here would result in a 
    // different error, since I don't have access to the viewHolder
    // here. To make this work, I tried preserving "viewHolder" in a 
    // field inside onBindViewHolder (which I don't think I'm 
    // supposed to do anyways), but the viewHolder reference was 
    // null, so it didn't work.
    setPreferenceTitle();
  }

  // This is my incorrect attempt at setting "myText" to the value of "preferenceTitle"
  private void setPreferenceTitle(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PreferenceWidgetSwitchCustom, 0, 0);

    try {
      int preferenceTitleId = a
          .getResourceId(R.styleable.PreferenceWidgetCustom_preferenceTitle, 0);

      ((SpecialCustomComponent) holder.itemView).setText(a.getResources().getString(preferenceTitleId));
    }
    finally {
      a.recycle();
    }
  }
}
```

I declared a custom attribute for my CustomPreference in attrs.xml that I am hoping to use to set the underlying "myText" attribute of my custom component in the layout.

**attrs.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="PreferenceWidgetCustom">
    <attr name="preferenceTitle" format="string" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The layout for each CustomPreference is defined here in preference_widget_custom.xml. Notice the attribute "myText", which is what I would like to set to the value of "preferenceTitle" defined above.

**preference_widget_custom.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SpecialCustomComponent
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:myText="this is the field I would like to be set by 'preferenceTitle'" />
```

I am using these preferences in a PreferenceScreen layout like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:title="Settings">
    <CustomPreference
        android:key="pref_one"
        app:preferenceTitle="Preference #1"/>
    <CustomPreference
        android:key="pref_two"
        app:preferenceTitle="Preference #2"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. As Martin pointed out a `styleable` is not really intended for strings anyways. As it turns out, using the built-in `android:title` attribute instead of a custom styleable made things really easy. All I have to do is call `this.getTitle()` to access its value from my `CustomPreference` class.

```js
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

  public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
      int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_widget_custom);
  }

  // other required constructor overloads omitted

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    setPreferenceTitle();
  }

  private void setPreferenceTitle() {
      ((SpecialCustomComponent) holder.itemView).setText(this.getTitle());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally wrong to provide a `string` resource as a `styleable` and that's why you're vastly overcomplicating a simple localization job. Any resource can be accessed with this pattern: `[<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`.

So this would be `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="title_preference_01">Title 01</string>
    <string name="summary_preference_01">Summary 01</string>
    <string name="title_preference_02">Title 02</string>
    <string name="summary_preference_02">Summary 02</string>
<resources>
```

Which then can be accessed throughput the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:title="Settings">

    <CustomPreference
        android:title="@string/title_preference_01"
        android:summary="@string/summary_preference_01"
        android:key="pref_one" />

    <CustomPreference
        android:title="@string/title_preference_02"
        android:summary="@string/summary_preference_02"
        android:key="pref_two" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[Localize your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) explains this all in high detail.

---

Besides, even if it were actual stylable values and not strings commonly used for localization, you'd still need to apply the `PreferenceWidgetCustom` style to `SpecialCustomComponent` in order to access it's values.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution fits my problem. Since I'm using a custom layout for CustomPreference, I need to set the 'myText' field of SpecialCustomComponent somehow. The way things are set up, setting 'title' on CustomPreference won't do any good, because the underlying layout only displays what is in the 'myText' field. Is there a way to access the value of 'android:title' and use it to set 'myText' field of SpecialCustomComponent, from the CustomPreference class? (I should also mention that SpecialCustomComponent is not mine, so I can't change it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that using a styleable attribute here is not correct. Noted.

Comment: The mere issue with that styleable approach is, that `styleable` cannot be localized alike `string` can - which may go unnoticed while only supporting a single one language, but it should be obvious how self-defeating it is, when trying to add another language. This misconception may originate from taking that component as given, despite it dearly abuses the framework. Starting over from scratch suggested.

Comment: Yes, good point. I can interchange a solution that uses string resources only easily enough. But I'm still trying to solve my problem of setting an attribute for SpecialCustomComponent (app:myText) from the value of an attribute from CustomPreference (could be android:title instead of a styleable, as you pointed out). Let me know if you have any suggestions on that.